# Django-cuser, request processing and threads

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I'm using Apache mod_wsgi to serve django. I'v also use Django-cuser middleware that makes user information always available. And i can't really understand how this middleware works. The specific source code:

```
class CuserMiddleware(object):
    @classmethod
    def get_user(cls, default=None):
        """
        Retrieve user info
        """
        return cls.__users.get(threading.current_thread(), default)

    @classmethod
    def set_user(cls, user):
        """
        Store user info
        """
        if isinstance(user, str):
            user = User.objects.get(username=user)
        cls.__users[threading.current_thread()] = user
```

Why use threading.current_thread() as a key for user? As i underastand Apache does not create different theads for requests.

Comment: Pretty much any WSGI server creates multiple threads. Django is a fully synchronous framework, so you need multiple threads or processes to handle concurrent requests. Anyway, it seems like a poor attempt to recreate[`threading.local`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.local).

Comment: so, CuserMiddleware, as a class, is shared between threads and class variables are accessible to each thread?

Comment: Yes, that's right.